# What is the opposite of 'sui generis'?

Tags: vocabulary, legal-latin, word-usage

Just wondering if there is an accepted opposite of this term, maybe something like 'generalis generis'?

Comment: Welcome to the site! In what kind of a context would you like to use what you are looking for? I think there is no one opposite, but it depends on the situation. One option is *solitus*, "usual".

Comment: Thanks, I was actually wondering if there was a technical term used in academic circles like *sui generis* - for a paper I was writing.

Comment: Also [_communis_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcommunis), common, universal, public. But I wouldn't use the Latin term in a paper.

Comment: There was a [suggested edit](https://latin.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2203) to add: "I would try to stick to the two-word Latin and say generis omnium, meaning the gender of us all, as opposed of one single entity." I rejected it, as it seemed to come from someone other than you, but I wrote this comment in case you want to add it after all. (To the anonymous user who suggested the edit (assuming it wasn't the OP): You should post a separate follow-up question instead of editing an old one. Registering an account also helps.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Unus multorum** means "one of many".

I gather that the phrase is comparable to "average Joe" in English, or "just one of the crowd"—the opposite of the uniqueness conveyed by *sui generis.* My Latin is not that solid; hopefully someone more knowledgeable will correct or confirm this. [This 1814 dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=8xNgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA812&dq=%22unus+multorum%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi91c7_7bvTAhXs4IMKHelVAWwQuwUIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22unus%20multorum%22&f=false) reports:

> **unus multorum et de multis**, is said of one, who is not distinguished for any thing, one of the vulgar.

People have occasionally used **Unus multorum** as a [pseudonym](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22unus+multorum%22+pseudonym&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22unus+multorum%22+pseudonym&tbm=bks) when they wanted to publish something anonymously.

Its most famous ancient use is probably in Horace's 9th Satire. Horace has encountered a bore while walking, and he can't get rid of him. They bump into Aristius Fuscus, a friend of Horace's. Horace tries to hint that Fuscus could save him from the bore. Fuscus, somewhat laughingly, isn't going along with it:

> "Certe, nescio quid, secreto velle loqui te
>   
> aiebas mecum." "Memini bene, sed meliori
>   
> tempore dicam: hodie tricesima sabbata, vin tu
>   
> curtis Iudaeis oppedere?" "Nulla mihi," inquam,
>   
> "religio est." "At mi, sum paulo infirmior, **unus**
>   
> **multorum**. Ignosces, alias loquar."
>
> Horace: "I can't remember what it was, but I'm sure you were saying you wanted to talk about something with me in private."
>
> Fuscus: "I remember it well, but I'll tell you at a better time: today is Passover [more precisely, a day when Jewish tradition forbids discussing business]. You wouldn't want to blow a fart at the circumcised Jews, would you?"
>
> Horace: "I've got no worries about that."
>
> Fuscus: "Well, I do. I'm not so strong-minded as you, I'm **like most people**. You'll forgive me, I'll talk some other time."

Note that **unus** is masculine. The feminine and neuter are **una multorum** and **unum multorum** respectively.

Comment: Good find! About the feminine: *una multorum* is one feminine thing from a mixed or undetermined group (example: one woman among all the people), *una multarum* is one feminine thing from a completely feminine group (example: one woman among all women).

Answer (score 4):

Since there has been no other answer, let me expand my comment into an answer.

I am not familiar with any technical term with a meaning opposite to *sui generis*.
If you want an adjective of similar origin, there is [*generalis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=generalis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
But the best Latin word I know for this is *solitus* (a form of [*solere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DS%3Aentry+group%3D51%3Aentry%3Dsoleo), see part II of the entry).

Notice that unlike *sui generis*, both *generalis* and *solitus* are adjectives and should be declined appropriately in use.

Answer (score 0):

ejusdem generis (of the same kind)

Comment: Hi, Shiny, and welcome to the site! Would you mind elaborating more on your answer, and why you think this is the best translation?